# What is the Date Format for the Healthcare Finder API?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

What is the date format for the [Healthcare Finder API](https://www.healthdata.gov/data/dataset/healthcare-finder-api)? I could not locate the answer in the API Schema.

Is it "Year - Day - Month" or "Year - Month - Day"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: "Year-Month-Day", or CCYY-MM-DD

Longer answer: The [Healthcare Finder API](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0) uses [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) to define the [API schema.](https://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v3.0.xsd).

So a line like `<xs:element name="InsuranceEffectiveDate" type="xs:date"/>` indicates that you should format the value according to XML Schema. This is a [reference page for the date type](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html)

(the reference to `xsd:date` on the linked page instead of `xs:date` as specified in the API schema document is a minor style choice, and not a cause for concern.)